# MailKit's IMessageSummary.Envelope.InReplyTo field is always null

Tags: c#, .net, imap, mailkit

I'm trying to implement a mail client using the IMAP protocol and MailKit library.

Regardless of how I configure the IMapClinet, the filed `IMessageSummary.Envelope.InReplyTo` is always null.

I'm using the Fetch method like the following:

```cs
client.Inbox.Fetch(startIndex, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.References | MessageSummaryItems.All | MessageSummaryItems.Headers);
```

And the interesting part is that the header for `In-Reply-To` is present and contains the value which is also present on the `References` header (they have the same value), but still, the mentioned field is always empty.

Am I missing something or do I need to evaluate the `Envelop` property somehow before accessing its fields?

**EDIT**

Here is the protocol log to be examined which was suggested by @jstedfast:

```
Connected to imap://127.0.0.1:143/
S: * OK IMAP4rev1 SmarterMail
C: A00000000 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS QUOTA XLIST CHILDREN ENABLE IDLE
S: A00000000 OK CAPABILITY completed
C: A00000001 AUTHENTICATE CRAM-MD5
S: + PDE5MTIwMTU2NjMugwNDIzQFJvamFuUEM+
C: cm9qYW5Acm9qYW5wYy5sb2NhbCAyNGRiYMTNjNzk5YTkyYjBhZjkxYTU3ZQ==
S: A00000001 OK CRAM authentication successful
C: A00000002 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS QUOTA XLIST CHILDREN ENABLE IDLE
S: A00000002 OK CAPABILITY completed
C: A00000003 LIST "" ""
S: * LIST (\Noselect) "/" ""
S: A00000003 OK LIST completed
C: A00000004 LIST "" "INBOX"
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Inbox) "/" "Inbox"
S: A00000004 OK LIST completed
C: A00000005 XLIST "" "*"
S: * XLIST (\HasNoChildren \Trash) "/" "Deleted Items"
S: * XLIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Drafts"
S: * XLIST (\HasNoChildren \Inbox) "/" "Inbox"
S: * XLIST (\HasNoChildren \Spam) "/" "Junk E-Mail"
S: * XLIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "/" "Sent Items"
S: A00000005 OK XLIST completed
C: A00000006 SELECT Inbox
S: * 1 EXISTS
S: * 0 RECENT
S: * OK [UNSEEN 1] Message 1 is first unseen
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 35] Predicted next UID
S: * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \Recent)
S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \Recent)] Folder flags
S: A00000006 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
C: A00000007 FETCH 1:* (UID FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE BODY BODY.PEEK[HEADER])
S: * 1 FETCH (UID 34 FLAGS () INTERNALDATE "7-Apr-2020 18:36:29 +0200" RFC822.SIZE 1536 ENVELOPE ("Tue, 07 Apr 2020 16:36:22 GMT" "Re: Hi dear friend" (({15}
S: test@mypc.local NIL "test" "mypc.local")) (({15}
S: test@mypc.local NIL "test" "mypc.local")) ((NIL NIL "test" "mypc.local")) ((NIL NIL "someone" "mypc.local")) NIL NIL NIL "<e938d94ca6ac4be085192f00cdc7fdd6@mypc.local>") BODY (("text" "plain" ("charset" "utf-8") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 242 11) ("text" "html" ("charset" "utf-8") NIL NIL "quoted-printable" 482 8) "alternative") BODY[HEADER] {468}
S: From: "test@mypc.local" <test@mypc.local>
S: To: <my@mypc.local>
S: Subject: Re: Hi dear friend
S: Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2020 16:36:22 GMT
S: Reply-To: test@mypc.local
S: Message-ID: <e938d94ca6ac4be085192f00cdc7fdd6@mypc.local>
S: MIME-Version: 1.0
S: Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
S:  boundary=de8794cbb22d4f6ea5a415917f9287ee
S: In-Reply-To: <specified-message-id>
S: References: <specified-message-id>
S: Disposition-Notification-To: test@mypc.local
S: X-SmarterMail-TotalSpamWeight: 0 (Authenticated)
S: 
S: )
S: A00000007 OK FETCH completed
```

Seems like the `In-Reply-To` is only present on the message's headers together with `References`.

**New question**: In the case where the `In-Reply-To` is not present on the `ENVELOPE`, is it a correct approach to manually examine the headers to find the value, or is it safer to use the `References` field which is provided by the `IMessageSummary` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailKit parses the `ENVELOPE` value returned by the IMAP server. If you look at the [Protocol Log](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#q-how-can-i-get-a-protocol-log-for-imap-pop3-or-smtp-to-see-what-is-going-wrong), do the IMAP server responses provide a non-null In-Reply-To value in the `ENVELOPE` response?

The `ENVELOPE` value has the following syntax:

```
envelope        = "(" env-date SP env-subject SP env-from SP
                  env-sender SP env-reply-to SP env-to SP env-cc SP
                  env-bcc SP env-in-reply-to SP env-message-id ")"

env-bcc         = "(" 1*address ")" / nil

env-cc          = "(" 1*address ")" / nil

env-date        = nstring

env-from        = "(" 1*address ")" / nil

env-in-reply-to = nstring

env-message-id  = nstring

env-reply-to    = "(" 1*address ")" / nil

env-sender      = "(" 1*address ")" / nil

env-subject     = nstring

env-to          = "(" 1*address ")" / nil
```

TL;DR, you'll be looking for the second-to-last string in the `ENVELOPE` parenthesized list value.

Edit:

Okay, now that you've pasted the log, we can take a look at what we got back from the server. Here's the relevant bit:

```
... ENVELOPE ("Tue, 07 Apr 2020 16:36:22 GMT" "Re: Hi dear friend" (({15}
S: test@mypc.local NIL "test" "mypc.local")) (({15}
S: test@mypc.local NIL "test" "mypc.local")) ((NIL NIL "test" "mypc.local")) ((NIL NIL "someone" "mypc.local")) NIL NIL NIL "<e938d94ca6ac4be085192f00cdc7fdd6@mypc.local>")
```

`env-date` = "Tue, 07 Apr 2020 16:36:22 GMT"

`env-subject` = "Re: Hi dear friend"

`env-from` = (("test@mypc.local" NIL "test" "mypc.local"))

`env-sender` = (("test@mypc.local" NIL "test" "mypc.local"))

`env-reply-to` = ((NIL NIL "test" "mypc.local"))

`env-to` = ((NIL NIL "someone" "mypc.local"))

`env-cc` = NIL

`env-bcc` = NIL

`env-in-reply-to` = NIL

`env-message-id` = ""

So the problem is that the IMAP server is telling MailKit that the In-Reply-To value is `NIL` (aka `null`).

Based on the raw headers that you are getting back for this message, it's clear that SmarterMail IMAP server is buggy in at least 2 ways:

1. The `env-in-reply-to` value is being sent as `NIL` when it should clearly be `"<specified-message-id>"`
2. The `env-sender` is being sent as a duplicate of `env-from`, but it *should* be `NIL` in your case based on the headers because it maps to the `Sender:` header which doesn't exist for your sample message.

Question for you: is `"<specified-message-id>"` literally what is in the headers? I wonder if maybe SmarterMail is sending `NIL` because that is *technically* invalid syntax and maybe SmarterMail is failing to parse that?

Just a thought.

Regarding the "New Question" in your post:

Yea, you can request the `In-Reply-To` header and manually parse it - that's perfectly fine. In fact, the way `MessageSummaryItems.References` works is that it asks for `HEADER.FIELDS (REFERENCES)` and then parses the raw header. Since you are *also* sending `MessageSummaryItems.Headers`, MailKit knows that it's pointless to ask for `References` again, since it'll be part of the `Headers` response.

I probably would recommend against requesting the full set of `MessageSummaryItems.Headers` (unless you have a specific need to fetch them all) since it's a lot of extra data that you don't need. Then again, when dealing with a broken IMAP server, maybe it's better to ask for `Headers` than `Envelope`.

The idea of `Envelope` is that it's more-or-less everything you need the client to know about in order to display a message-list to the user.

The reason that MailKit has `MessageSummaryItems.References` (and not any other individual header) is because the `References` header is needed in order to do proper threading using the `MailKit.MessageThreader.Thread()` methods. It will make use of the `Envelope.InReplyTo` value as well, but it isn't required, I don't think, because technically, `References` is *supposed* to have the same `msg-id` token as one of its values.

The `References` header is the chain of `Message-Id` header values back to the root of the "conversation" (it's a little more complex than that since clients are allowed to trim some `msg-id` values once the list gets too long, but that's the general idea).

Comment: can you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope my explanation is helpful!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the in-depth explanation. To answer the question, the actual Message-Id that I have used is in the format of fb1c45@mypc.local which I assume is parseable by the mail server, therefore it really looks like a bug in Smarter Mail. So my safe bet is to request the In-Reply-To header and use its value.
1 more question. If I want to store the full received message file and the headers in the database, who do I request everything at once? :)

Comment: You can't request everything at once in MailKit (the API doesn't support it). I'm not sure that would be a good idea anyway since it would have to download all of a user's mail into memory to return it to the caller. That could be gigabytes of data.

Comment: OK, then I know! Thanks a lot. :)